# Default values for missing maven properties when expanded in spring application.properties

Tags: spring, maven, properties, pom.xml, configurationproperties

If a property `@property.absent@` defined in `application.properties` cannot be expanded (it is not defined in `pom.xml`), the bound value is the literal `@property.absent@`. Is there an easy way to override this with custom defaults (e.g. null), esp. in auto-configuration in conjunction with `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Answer (score 0):

application.yml file:

```
test:
 property: @property.absent@
```

Configuration properties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
public class TestConfigurationProperties {

private String property = "your default value";

//Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: Yes, had tried that, but somehow hadn't worked. To make matters concrete, here's a stripped-down project illustrating this: [expansion](https://github.com/zmeeagain/expansion)

Comment: You have not used '@Value' annotation
For your purposes please use constant value in '@Configuration' properties , like private String absent = "Hello";

Comment: Yes, didn't add `@Value` in `ConfigurationProperties` as it does not work. Ideally I would like to combine the benefit of mapping complex nested config properties to source (using ConfigurationProperties) with defaults.

Comment: In case of that try to assign default value like private String a = "default"

Comment: Yes, had tried this too, this would work if the property were not there at all in `application.properties`. In this case however it's still defaulted to `@absent@`.